# Play Framework 2.5 - getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError on lauch

Tags: java, playframework

Hello I am getting this error 4 or 5 times when lauching Play app:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: play.routes.compiler.inject.twirl.forwardsRouter_Scope0$forwardsRouter._display_(Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/reflect/Manifest;)Lplay/twirl/api/Appendable;
    at play.routes.compiler.inject.twirl.forwardsRouter_Scope0$forwardsRouter$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(forwardsRouter.template.scala:27)
    at play.routes.compiler.inject.twirl.forwardsRouter_Scope0$forwardsRouter$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(forwardsRouter.template.scala:27)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.routes.compiler.inject.twirl.forwardsRouter_Scope0$forwardsRouter.apply(forwardsRouter.template.scala:27)
    at play.routes.compiler.InjectedRoutesGenerator$.generateRouter(RoutesGenerator.scala:210)
    at play.routes.compiler.InjectedRoutesGenerator$.generate(RoutesGenerator.scala:154)
    at play.routes.compiler.RoutesCompiler$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(RoutesCompiler.scala:88)
    at play.routes.compiler.RoutesCompiler$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(RoutesCompiler.scala:87)
    at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.map(Either.scala:536)
    at play.routes.compiler.RoutesCompiler$.compile(RoutesCompiler.scala:87)
    at play.sbt.routes.RoutesCompiler$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$7.apply(RoutesCompiler.scala:137)
    at play.sbt.routes.RoutesCompiler$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$7.apply(RoutesCompiler.scala:136)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at play.sbt.routes.RoutesCompiler$$anonfun$6.apply(RoutesCompiler.scala:136)
    at play.sbt.routes.RoutesCompiler$$anonfun$6.apply(RoutesCompiler.scala:134)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.web.incremental.package$.syncIncremental(package.scala:228)
    at play.sbt.routes.RoutesCompiler$.compileRoutes(RoutesCompiler.scala:134)
    at play.sbt.routes.RoutesCompiler$$anonfun$4.apply(RoutesCompiler.scala:127)
    at play.sbt.routes.RoutesCompiler$$anonfun$4.apply(RoutesCompiler.scala:126)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (compile:playRoutes) java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: play.routes.compiler.inject.twirl.forwardsRouter_Scope0$forwardsRouter._display_(Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/reflect/Manifest;)Lplay/twirl/api/Appendable;
[error] p.c.s.n.PlayRequestHandler - Exception caught in Netty
scala.MatchError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: play.routes.compiler.inject.twirl.forwardsRouter_Scope0$forwardsRouter._display_(Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/reflect/Manifest;)Lplay/twirl/api/Appendable; (of class java.lang.NoSuchMethodError)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:44)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:44)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:44)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:40)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17)
    at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:377)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compile(PlayReload.scala:17)
```

I can not figure out what is causing this problem..Can someone help me?
I am using IntelliJ to manage my play application (was also created from there) 
I tried running clean from activator , but it did not help.
So its probably some incompatibility in libraries..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: I need more information than you're doing.

Comment: Should I include build.sbt , plugins.sbt in post?

Comment: @Martin, yes include those files and also what you have tried already. Moreover, please, follow Katie's advice as they are extreme pertinent here.

Comment: @Martin Were you able to figure out the issue? Funny, after about 4 years I am facing the same issue.

BTW this is a good question and needs no other fluff IF they have encountered/solved this already. For others, it is a chance for moderation ‍♂️